# Gc Overhead Limit Exceeded while querying db java

Tags: java, sql, bigdata, heap-memory

I have big db (~ 1 billion rows) 
 I want to query the db, make some logic and write to file all the rows
I made java program that query the db and writes the rows to file but I get GC Overhead limit 
I understand why I am getting the gc overhead but I am not sure how to solve it..

Comment: Please provide the code where the problem is occuring. Without seeing how you do it, we cannot give suggestions on how to improve your programm and prevent the problem.

Comment: It would be good to share the code. Ideally i would have looked into increasing the memory, but getting a GC overhead is sort of a black box. Better share the code and let us know if there is any memory intensive operation you are doing when you say you have used "some logic"?

Comment: Are you querying *all* of the 1 billion rows? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: What is the alternative? @PhilippPloder

Comment: If you truly understand the problem, then you know that nobody can help you without much more details then this.

Comment: @user3100708 Show us some code so we can see what you are doing exactly